# SlidesJS hide works one time only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

i made 5 slideshows and i made a hide show jquery for them, my problem is after i show the hidden slideshows they dont respond anymore its just a static image of the last pic of the slideshow.

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="slides">
            <img src="img/room1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/bathroom1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/diningroom1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/balcony1.jpg" />
        </div>


        <div id="slides0">
            <img src="img/room1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/bathroom1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/diningroom1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/balcony1.jpg" />
        </div>


        <div id="slides1">
            <img src="img/room.jpg" />
            <img src="img/bathroom.jpg" />
            <img src="img/diningroom.jpg" />
            <img src="img/balcony.jpg" />
        </div>


        <div id="slides2">
            <img src="img/room1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/bathroom1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/diningroom1.jpg" />
            <img src="img/balcony1.jpg" />
        </div>


        <div id="slides3">
            <img src="img/room.jpg" />
            <img src="img/bathroom.jpg" />
            <img src="img/diningroom.jpg" />
            <img src="img/balcony.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

then my hide show jquery is

```
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
    $("#slides").show();
          $("#slides0,#slides1,#slides2,#slides3").hide();
    $("#intro").click(function(){
        $("#slides0,#slides1,#slides2,#slides3").hide();
    });

    $("#intro").click(function(){
        $("#slides").show();
    });
    $("#single").click(function(){
        $("#slides,#slides1,#slides2,#slides3").hide();
    });

    $("#single").click(function(){
        $("#slides0").show();
    });
    $("#double").click(function(){
        $("#slides,#slides0,#slides2,#slides3").hide();
    });

    $("#double").click(function(){
        $("#slides1").show();
    });
    $("#family").click(function(){
        $("#slides,#slides0,#slides1,#slides3").hide();
    });

    $("#family").click(function(){
        $("#slides2").show();
    });
    $("#deluxe").click(function(){
        $("#slides,#slides0,#slides1,#slides2").hide();
    });

    $("#deluxe").click(function(){
        $("#slides3").show();
    });

});
```

and the sliders jquery that SlideJs made that i added for multiple slideshows

```
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 300,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4000,
      swap: true
    }
  });
  $('#slides0').slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 300,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4000,
      swap: true
    }
  });

  $('#slides1').slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 300,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4000,
      swap: true
    }
  });

  $('#slides2').slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 300,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4000,
      swap: true
    }
  });

  $('#slides3').slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 300,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4000,
      swap: true
    }
  });
});
```

This is the webpage:[Slider](http://jcuizon.host56.com/rooms.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are hiding/showing slideshows after Slide.Js has been call, of cause they don't work. try to wrap your last block of codes in a function, and call it every time you execute your second block of codes

first you shouldn't have repeated these functions, do something like this

```
function active_slidesjs(slidesID){//slidesID is your elements
  slidesID.slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 300,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 4000,
      swap: true
    }
  });
}
```

then when you click your elements, call the function like this

```
$("#single").click(function(){
    $("#slides,#slides1,#slides2,#slides3").hide();
    active_slidesjs($(this));
});
```

The syntax might be wrong, but the idea is there

Comment: Thanks man, i didnt make function though. i went ahead and went the long way lol no functions, but in the future i will change this into functions so the code wont be long